# Cannot run program "executable" : while trying to run Karate UI tests in firefox browser

Tags: karate

I have added below line in karate-config.js to have my UI tests run in firefox
'''
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'executable' });
'''

But I am getting below error while running test on my local machine:
'''
ERROR com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command error: [executable, --port=4444] - Cannot run program "executable" (in directory "target/geckodriver_1692338736986"): error=2, No such file or directory
11:35:43.340 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: start failed, options: {type=geckodriver, executable=executable, target=null}
'''

Can someone please help

Comment: sorry no one can help figure out if you got the path of the executable right. try to refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver or stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+geckodriver+executable